# noob- get webtest installed in GGTS

Tags: grails

I'm 2 days into web development using grails in GGTS. I'm following along with a book. The book uses the command line. So far this has been great, but now the book is using webtest. I've installed webtest on the command line, but how do I get it working inside of GGTS?

EDIT: I found the grails console inside of GGTS.. here's my output

```
grails> install-plugin webtest
Problem executing: install-plugin webtest
Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java (Dec 26, 2013, 11:22:59 AM)
---- System.out ----
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:webtest:3.0.1

---- System.err ----

------System.out:-----------
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:webtest:3.0.1
```

EDIT: After setting log level to 'warm' in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.5.0.M1/collab-todo/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/hibernate-2.1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/resources-1.1.6/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/cache-1.0.0/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/database-migration-1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/tomcat-2.1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/ivy-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/jars/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/bundles/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/src/libs/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/src/libs/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/dist/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/dist/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/cached-installed-plugins/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/cached-installed-plugins/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/plugins/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-webtest/tags/RELEASE_3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-webtest/tags/RELEASE_3.0.1/grails-webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.5.0.M1/collab-todo/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/hibernate-2.1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/resources-1.1.6/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/cache-1.0.0/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/database-migration-1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/jquery-1.8.0/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/projects/collab-todo/plugins/tomcat-2.1.1/lib/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/ivy-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/jars/webtest-3.0.1.jar
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/webtest/bundles/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/src/libs/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/src/libs/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/dist/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/dist/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/cached-installed-plugins/webtest-3.0.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.grails/2.1.1/cached-installed-plugins/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /usr/share/grails/2.1.1/plugins/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-webtest/tags/RELEASE_3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-webtest/tags/RELEASE_3.0.1/grails-webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1!webtest.jar:
      /home/adminuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/webtest/3.0.1/webtest-3.0.1.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#webtest;3.0.1: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:webtest:3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `install-plugin` command [is now deprecated](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html).

Try adding the [following line](http://grails.org/plugin/webtest) to your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
compile ":webtest:3.0.1"
```

Then try launching the grails application from GGTS.

PS: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I switched to geb+spock because these seemed more current. Still, this comment is helpful- I didn't realize `install-plugin` was deprecated. The GGTS plugin manager seems to use install-plugin, so that's confusing!

Comment: No, I'm not behind a proxy.